# Zurb Foundation responsive text above an image

Tags: css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

Hope you are all doing great.

I am new to zurb foundation and really enjoying the responsive framework and its possibilities of design!

Although zurb is awesome, I am stuck at creating this design which I am sure it can be done.

Basically what I am trying to do is to have a resposive text which is part of the "bar" id and will stay at it's position even though the size changes.

Currently the text "small-block-grid-5 span" is moving freely.

I have done a jsFiddle for your reference and at the very bottom of the code I have provided what the final look I am trying to achieve.http://jsfiddle.net/mrzoogle/pmYVQ/2/

HTML

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="large-8 columns">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns">
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
                     <h1><a href="#"><img id="mn-image" src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/df9e/0a3gam4mjjf2e31bg.jpg?size_id=5" alt="testimage"> </a></h1>

                    <div class="img-wrap">
                         <h1 style="margin-bottom:-15px;"><a href="#"><img id="bar" src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/b77f/ouskaxv6jo2c925bg.jpg?size_id=5" alt="testbar"/></a></h1>

                        <ul class="small-block-grid-5">
                            <li><span class="placeholder">Hi</span><strong>Text1</strong>

                            </li>
                            <li><span class="placeholder">HiHi</span><strong>Test2</strong>

                            </li>
                            <li><span class="placeholder">Hi</span><strong>Test3Test3</strong>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <img src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/9690/6j1vy7zs7h5qibobg.jpg?size_id=2">
                    </div>
                     <h1>Final Result</h1>
                   <img src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/6e43/063qj9wij0cd0babg.jpg?size_id=6">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .panel h1{
    width: 100%;
}

.img-wrap h1{
    width: 100%;
}

.img-wrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    img {
        position: relative;
        bottom: 40px;
    }
    ul {
        position: absolute;
        top: -40px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    ul span {
        color: white;
        font: bold 20px/45px helvetica, Sans-Serif;
        letter-spacing: -1px;
    }
}
.small-block-grid-5 strong {
    display: block;
    font-size:23px;
    line-height:52px;
}
.small-block-grid-5 li {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Thanks for your time and looking forward to learn something new!!

Kind Regards,
Z.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've mocked up something that you could work with.

To replicate your design I would use the gradient features in CSS3 and fallback to a solid colour for browsers that don't support it.

Then you're left with just floating the li left and adding a 1px right border to them.

I didn't bother about removing the last borther, but you can do that with a :nth declaration.

here's a quick code pen. - http://codepen.io/justincavery/full/qdokp